# How can a Rust trait object return another trait object?

Tags: rust

How can I attempt something like the following in Rust?

The builder class is a trait object which returns another trait object (type erasure) where the implementation that is selected is defined by the specific object of the builder trait that we are using.

```rust
trait Builder {
    // I want this trait to return a trait object
    fn commits(&self) -> dyn Commit;

    fn finish(&self);
}

trait Commit {
}

struct FooBuilder {
}

struct FooCommit {
}

impl Builder for FooBuilder {
    fn commits(&self) -> impl Commit {
        FooCommit{ }
    }

    fn finish(&self) {
    }
}

fn get_commits(b: &Builder) {
    // trait object returns a trait
    let c = b.commits();
}

fn main() {
    let b = FooBuilder{};
    get_commits(&b);
    b.finish();
}
```

Comment: A trait is not an object, it is a property of an object. You could return something which implements a trait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem returning trait objects from trait methods in Rust:

```
trait Foo {
  fn bar(&self) -> Box<dyn Bar>;
}
```

One thing to notice is that you need to return `Box<dyn Bar>`, not `dyn Bar`, since size of `dyn Bar` is not known at compiled time, which renders it useless.

When you implement this trait, the signature has to match, so it should return `Box<dyn Bar>`, not `impl Bar`:

```
impl Foo for MyFoo {
  fn bar(&self) -> Box<dyn Bar> {
    Box::new(MyBar{})
  }
}
```