# Traits returning a trait: In some cases works, in others it doesn't

Tags: rust

I need to implement a trait that is returning the `futures::StreamExt` trait.

In general this sounds easy and there are several answers to this e.g. [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60143046/how-can-a-rust-trait-object-return-another-trait-object).

I tried this with `StreamExt` but this does - for some reason - not work. Here my sample code:

```rust
// [dependencies]
// futures = "0.3.6"
// async-std = { version = "1.6.5", features = ["attributes", "unstable"] } // interval function is unstable atm.
use std::time::Duration;

use futures::StreamExt;

trait StreamProvidingTrait {
  fn returnastream(self: &Self) -> Box<dyn StreamExt<Item=i32>>;
}

struct StreamProvider {}

impl StreamProvidingTrait for StreamProvider {
  fn returnastream(self: &Self) -> Box<dyn StreamExt<Item=i32>> {
    return Box::new(async_std::stream::interval(Duration::from_millis(1000)).map(|_| 1));
  }
}

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() {
  let mut counter = 0;
  let object = StreamProvider {};

  // creates a stream
  let worx = object.returnastream();
  // mappes the stream into something....
  let mut mapped_stream = worx.map(|_| {
    counter = counter + 1;
    counter
  });
  // subscribing to the items
  while let item = mapped_stream.next().await {
    match item {
      Some(value) => println!("{}", value),
      _ => {}
    }
  }
}
```

And here the error:

```
Compiling traittest v0.1.0 (/Users/andre/repos/traittest)
warning: the trait `futures_util::stream::stream::StreamExt` cannot be made into an object
--> /Users/andre/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-util-0.3.6/src/stream/stream/mod.rs:1326:8
|
1326 |     fn poll_next_unpin(&mut self, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>>
|        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait cannot be made into an object because method `poll_next_unpin` references the `Self` type in its `where` clause
|
= note: `#[warn(where_clauses_object_safety)]` on by default
= warning: this was previously accepted by the compiler but is being phased out; it will become a hard error in a future release!
= note: for more information, see issue #51443 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/51443>

error[E0038]: the trait `futures_util::stream::stream::StreamExt` cannot be made into an object
--> src/main.rs:6:36
|
6    |   fn returnastream(self: &Self) -> Box<dyn StreamExt<Item=i32>>;
|                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `futures_util::stream::stream::StreamExt` cannot be made into an object
|
::: /Users/andre/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-util-0.3.6/src/stream/stream/mod.rs:226:8
|
226  |     fn next(&mut self) -> Next<'_, Self>
|        ---- the trait cannot be made into an object because method `next` references the `Self` type in its return type
...
976  |     fn by_ref(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
  |        ------ the trait cannot be made into an object because method `by_ref` references the `Self` type in its return type
  ...
      1381 |     fn select_next_some(&mut self) -> SelectNextSome<'_, Self>
  |        ---------------- the trait cannot be made into an object because method `select_next_some` references the `Self` type in its return type

  error[E0038]: the trait `futures_util::stream::stream::StreamExt` cannot be made into an object
      --> src/main.rs:12:36
      |
      12   |   fn returnastream(self: &Self) -> Box<dyn StreamExt<Item=i32>> {
    |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `futures_util::stream::stream::StreamExt` cannot be made into an object
        |
    ::: /Users/andre/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-util-0.3.6/src/stream/stream/mod.rs:226:8
        |
        226  |     fn next(&mut self) -> Next<'_, Self>
    |        ---- the trait cannot be made into an object because method `next` references the `Self` type in its return type
    ...
        976  |     fn by_ref(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
      |        ------ the trait cannot be made into an object because method `by_ref` references the `Self` type in its return type
      ...
          1381 |     fn select_next_some(&mut self) -> SelectNextSome<'_, Self>
      |        ---------------- the trait cannot be made into an object because method `select_next_some` references the `Self` type in its return type

      error: aborting due to 2 previous errors; 1 warning emitted

      For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0038`.
      error: could not compile `traittest`.

      To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.

          Process finished with exit code 101
```

When I exchange the `StreamExt` trait with my own one, this code works perfectly.

```rust
trait SomeTrait {
  fn returnatrait(self: &Self) -> Box<dyn SomeOtherTrait>;
}

trait SomeOtherTrait {
  fn sayHelloWorld(&self);
}

struct DummyStruct {}

impl SomeOtherTrait for DummyStruct {
  fn sayHelloWorld(&self) {
    println!("hello world");
  }
}

struct Implementation {}

impl SomeTrait for Implementation {
  fn returnatrait(self: &Self) -> Box<dyn SomeOtherTrait> {
    return Box::new(DummyStruct{});
  }
}

fn main() {
  let implementation = Implementation{};

  let worx = implementation.returnatrait();

  worx.sayHelloWorld();
}
```

What's wrong here? There's obviously something I don't understand. Please help me understand this!

Comment: What happens if you add a function like `fn get_self(&self) -> &Self` to your trait? This seems to stick out in the error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function returning a trait can use the `impl Trait` syntax to return an opaque type that implements the trait. A trait method returning a trait currently [doesn't support](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2071-impl-trait-existential-types.html#motivation) this feature and requires the trait to be returned as a trait object - a dynamically dispatched reference or smart pointer such as `Box` or `Rc`. Not all traits are [object-safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html#object-safety-is-required-for-trait-objects), though, and the bad news is that `StreamExt` is among those that aren't, for reasons pointed out by the compiler, such as referencing `Self` in method return types and `where` clauses.

The good news, however, is that this is not a problem: `StreamExt` is an extension trait, one that provides a blanket implementation for all types that implement `Stream`. So you don't need to bother returning a `dyn StreamExt` trait object, you can return a `dyn Stream` one, and you'll still get access to `StreamExt` methods simply by requesting them with `use StreamExt`. In other words, you can just replace `Box<dyn StreamExt>` with `Box<dyn Stream>` in the return type of your trait.

Another issue you might encounter is that `Box<dyn Stream>` doesn't work on methods that need to move the stream, which includes many methods provided by `StreamExt`. Those will require the stream to be pinned, which can be fixed by returning `Pin<Box<dyn Stream>>` instead of `Box<dyn Stream>`. There is even a `boxed()` method on `StreamExt` that pins and boxes the stream in one operation; code that uses it would look like this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1acefd7b6d9542e68c4352524cb81965)):

```
use futures::stream::{Stream, StreamExt};
use std::pin::Pin;

trait StreamProvidingTrait {
    fn returnastream(&self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = i32>>>;
}

struct StreamProvider {}

impl StreamProvidingTrait for StreamProvider {
    fn returnastream(&self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = i32>>> {
        return tokio::stream::once(0).boxed();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let provider = StreamProvider {};
    let stream = provider.returnastream();
    let _fut = stream.into_future();
}
```